# Truffle test doesn't seem to finish before "succeeding", and doesn't wait for transactionHash of a sent tx

Tags: unit-testing, ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle, ganache

Quick problem I've been slamming my head against since last night,

My truffle (v5.2.3) test file performs **two (2)** tests, that serially `call()` then actually send a transaction to make persistent changes on my smart contract's storage. These tests are as follow (sorry for the dumped file, I've minimized as much as I could):

```js
const PassportManager = artifacts.require("PassportManager");

contract("PassportManager", accounts => {
    it("should initialize a new passport linked with the current user's address", () => {
        let this_address = accounts[0];
        let this_nickname = "John Doe";
        let meta;
        
    return PassportManager.deployed()
        .then(instance => {
            meta = instance;
            console.log("Test1 on PassportManager address: " + meta.address);
            return meta.initPassport.call(this_nickname);
        })
        .then(returned_tuple => {
            assert.equal(returned_tuple[0], this_nickname, "Nickname, passed and returned by PassportManager.initPassport(), should match!");
            assert.equal(returned_tuple[1], this_address, "Controller address, passed and returned by PassportManager.initPassport(), should match!");
            //If we're here, it means the previous call() has succeeded. Now,
            //let's take things up a notch and let's actually send a transaction that changes the state of the blockchain.
            //Remember: We can't check for return values with a transaction, we have to debug the tx id manually.
            //#NOTE: We passed an extra parameter here. For more info on this special parameter object, check out:
            //https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts#making-a-transaction
            const result = meta.initPassport.sendTransaction(this_nickname, {from: accounts[0]});
            result.on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
                console.log('TxHash', hash);
            });
        });
    });
    
    it("should add an identity file sha256 hash to a controlled passport", () => {
        let this_address = accounts[0];
        let doc_hash = "0x21f3a9de43f07d855f49b946a10c30df432e8af95311435f77daf894216dcd41";
        let meta;
        
    return PassportManager.deployed()
        .then(instance => {
            meta = instance;
            console.log("Test2 on PassportManager address: " + meta.address);
            return meta.addIDFileToPassport.call(this_address, doc_hash);
        })
        .then(returned_tuple => {
            assert.equal(returned_tuple[0], this_address, "Passport controller, passed and returned by PassportManager.addIDFileToPassport(), should match!");
            assert.equal(returned_tuple[1], doc_hash, "Document hash (bytes32), passed and returned by PassportManager.addIDFileToPassport(), should match!");
            assert.equal(returned_tuple[2], 1, "Trust score of newly added doc_hash should be 1!");
            //Now let's actually pass a concrete, actuallly persistent transaction instead of a call.
            const result = meta.addIDFileToPassport.sendTransaction(this_address, doc_hash, {from: accounts[0]});
            result.on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
                console.log('TxHash', hash);
            });
            console.log("what the hell");
        });
    });
    
  /*it("return false", () => {
    assert(0==1);
  });
  */
});
```

The first test calls, then sends a transaction just fine! At every `truffle test` that I run, I get nice, expected log results in my console:

```
Test1 on PassportManager address: 0x871bbABdAeA0721FEB5529A07119edC7f05aB508
    ✓ should initialize a new passport linked with the current user's address (71ms)
TxHash 0x0760cb2738da2a21cc404e0627e1008599fe81f2c3a6914a1b06ff712dc8adca
```

and now it continues to the 2nd test, **where for some reason it doesn't send the transaction, even though the call succeeds**!

```
Test2 on PassportManager address: 0x871bbABdAeA0721FEB5529A07119edC7f05aB508
what the hell
    ✓ should add an identity file sha256 hash to a controlled passport (58ms)
```

The assertions are succeeding, the returned results from my contract call are logged, we even reach the frustrated little `what the hell` which is **BELOW** the `sendTransaction`, but I never get a TxHash like on the sent transaction of the 1st `it()` test!

What is even weirder is that if I add a 3rd `it()` test, it works as expected:
Uncomment the `it("return false", () => { assert(0==1); });` from my test block, and **lo and behold:**

```
Test2 on PassportManager address: 0x87465190eCBa7C287143f07653462a87464b1AbA
what the hell
    ✓ should add an identity file sha256 hash to a controlled passport (119ms)
    1) return false
TxHash 0x9226311347487d294b0bcf5bc1f535636fe886f08dfa327f15de43318aad37d7

    Events emitted during test:
    ---------------------------

    /* I even get proper emitted event data from my contract! */

    ---------------------------
```

I've been losing hair on this since yesterday, and I smell some sort of concurrency/timing problem. Is there any way to control the sequence of sent transactions, or wait for one to be submitted and mined before moving on with the tests?
The weird sequence of printed `console.log()`s **(for example, the third test failing before test 2 actually prints out the txHash and event data)** is maybe pointing towards something like that, but I thought the `result.on()` block would ensure we're waiting for the tx to be mined!

Comment: Can you check the tx `0x0760cb27...` (from the first `it` section), whether its `data` field is empty (`0x`) or filled (8 bytes of the `initPassport()` signature and the string as argument)? Also, does your contract have a fallback/receive function? ... I've never seen this approach using `method.sendTransaction()` so I'm unsure whether it's a valid use. Normally, it's used as `contract.sendTransaction()` for sending a low-level transaction object as the [docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#sending-ether-triggering-the-fallback-function) suggest.